# Do 'it' and 'there' refer to the correct parts of this sentence?

Tags: subjects, subordinate-clauses

In the following sentence, the 'it' in the bold part should refer to Acid Grassland and the 'there' should refer to the 'roughs' (rough areas on a golf course).

*"Frighteningly, some of the dangers lie on the Golf Course where there is generally far better management than elsewhere. The roughs support some of the best remaining areas of Acid Grassland but it won’t be long **before it is gone there too.**"*

I think it is clear what the sentence means, but is it grammatically correct? The subject in the first clause is the roughs, so simplistically, the 'it' might refer to that.

How does one analyze the sentence and is there a better way of expressing it, if wrong?

Comment: Allow me....Forbearance is virtue so is common sense. **It** might not be long before it does not prevail **here**. it and there, and it and here are purrfectly gammatical. Yes, I like cats....

Comment: Everything you wrote is right, and the sentence still takes more than one read to make sure of getting it for sure. There's also another *it* after *but*. I'd try this: "Acid Grassland, **which** before long will be gone there too."

Comment: The antecedent for *it* probably exists in a prior sentence: _**Acid Grassland** is diminishing. The roughs support some of the best remaining areas of Acid Grassland, but it won’t be long before **it** is gone there too._

Comment: @TinfoilHat There is a dummy it and an it with an antecedent in the same sentence....

Comment: @Lambie: There isn't a proper antecedent for the second *it* within that sentence.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes, there is: best remaining areas of Acid Grassland = it. I don't get some comments around here. I really do not.

Comment: @Lambie: *areas* would = *they*

Comment: @Lambie 'antecedent' has to be actual words, not the idea they convey (however accurately). 'Acid Grassland' (I'm not sure whether some knowledgeable body has awarded such an environment capitalisation) could be the antecedent, as is seen by replacing with 'desert' (and ignoring everything but the grammar involved).

Comment: What @TinfoilHat & Edwin said. It's not a *serious* problem, but I found the lack a proper antecedent for the second ***it*** at least *slightly* distracting. If it had been me writing it, I'd probably have rephrased somehow.

Comment: @Lambie - 1st comment. Wrong `it` highlighted. For the second `it` I don't know whether it apples to forbearance or common sense.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - excellent. Thanks.

Comment: @TinfoilHat - the article is about Acid Grassland, so yes there is an antecedent. I'll add the sentence that starts the paragraph to the question above.

Answer (score 2):

It is, as you say, clear what is being said.  But I do have doubts about the grammar in one respect.  Just as the noun phrase *The Roughs* (which I have corrects to what I assume is the name of part of the North Downs in Hampshire) is singular and so ought to be the subject of the **singular** verb *supports*, so ***areas*** <of acid grassland (surely lower case?)>, being plural, should be followed by the plural pronoun *they* and the plural verb *are*.

You could easily avoid the main dilemma by concluding:

> ...acid grassland, which before long will be lost from there also.

Alternatively, if you feel the emphasis of *but* is too important, and I can see the merit of this,

> ... but it will not be long before the acid grassland is lost form there also.

If neither of these will do, you can get away '"before *it* is lost...".  It is only pedants like me that will notice, and even I would not have noticed without your drawing my attention to it (or them).

Comment: *The roughs* means the rough areas on golf courses, as noted by the OP in the first sentence. No cap, plural agreement: *The roughs support . . .*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Ah, of course (pardon the pun).  In that case, why would you not replace 'there' with 'these'?  I'll delete my answer, which you have read for what it was worth.

Comment: Thanks. Both of your alternatives are improvements in readability (though I don't really like the repetition of acid grassland).

Comment: @ William Morris You're welcome:  I'm sure you can think of a better alternative.